# Include problems when unit testing

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

When I unit test classes I need to change the include paths, but then the website it self won't work. Thus every time I test I need to change almost all include paths in the files and after testing change them back again. This obviously is not practical.

I roughly understand why this happens; because test files are not in the root directory.

Question: How can I keep unit test files in the same folder as files being tested without having to change the include paths?

I tried defining a PATH constant. This also didn't work because the file defining the constant redefines it everytime it is included, making it useless.

```php
require_once 'database/CrudTest.php';
require_once 'UserModel.php';
require_once 'database/UserCrud.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserModelTest extends TestCase{
....
```

To test classes I have to put '../' before every include in every file needed for the test. Then remove them after test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't depend on the include path or relative path for these requires. You can use `__DIR__` to get the absolute path to the directory the test file is in, then set the rest of the path to the required file relative to that.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/database/CrudTest.php';
```

I'm not 100% certain this path is correct because I'm not sure if I understood you correctly about where these files are relative to the test file. You may need to use

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../database/CrudTest.php';
```

but regardless, the general idea is the same. This way the path will be correct regardless of the relative location of the calling script or the current working directory.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction, I asked this in my last hour on friday and actually forgot about the question. Anyway solution works, appreciated!

Comment: It's okay! You're welcome. It's not really that late anyway. I've had people accept an answer like two years later haha